# Symfony - Prefix all my routes with a version

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle

Hi I would like to version my API. So I would like t prefix my roote with a version. like that?

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml

controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        name: '{version}'
```

It works bit I would like to add a requirement to check the version.

Like:

```
requirements:
     version:  v1|v2
```

I don't find any documentation talking about that. Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the FOSRestBundle there is a complete chapter about versioning.

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/versioning.html

The FOSBundle has an option for versioning.

```
#app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    versioning:
        enabled: true
        resolvers:
            query: true # Query parameter: /users?version=v1
            custom_header: true # X-Accept-Version header
            media_type: # Accept header
                enabled: true
                regex: '/(v|version)=(?P<version>[0-9\.]+)/'
```